# Which elasticsearch-server version for spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i am updateing to latest spring-data-elasticsearch version 3.1.9 and i am unsure what elasticsearch-server version i should use
here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch
in the Compatibility Matrix version 6.2.2 is mentioned

but when i look the resulting spring boot jar file, a jar file elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar is referenced

when printing the dependency tree, i see:

```
|    +--- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:6.2.2 -> 6.4.3
```

however, in the pom.xml of spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.9 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/52e1525710b7125260e978dd4c29ef8e50001dd5/pom.xml
version 6.2.2 is referenced

which elasticsearch-server version should i install? 6.2.2 or 6.4.3 ?

Comment: You may try it without Spring-data-elasticsearch. https://github.com/Georges73/projet-es-highlevel-sb-react/blob/master/back-end/achille/pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when checking the [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/85e508e6ac5a52062cc9f985e42b3752e1ee4f78/pom.xml#L22) from version 3.1.10.RELEASE you'll see that this version was built with ES 6.2.2. What other dependencies do you have that might pull a different version of ES? You can check this with `mvn dependency:tree` and see which library pulls this newer version of ES. As of which ES to install: Probably 6.2.2 would be the better choice, because there might be incompatible changes between 6.2.2 and 6.4.3.

If possible, you could try the latest 3.2.0.RC2 version which is built using ES 6.8.1